# Multiple if conditions in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with links and was trying to filter those and got stuck. I was able to write a function for multiple if statements explicitly but was looking to write it directly in the list comprehension.

I have tried multiple ways `(i.startswith(), "https" in i)` to write it but couldn't figure it out.

This is the list comprehension:

```
[i.a.get('href') for i in link_data if i != None]
```

Output:

```
['/gp/redirect.html/ref=as',
'https://www.google.com/',
'https://www.amazon.com/',
'/gp/redirect.html/ref=gf']
```

I only require links which starts with `https`.

How can I write this if condition in my list comprehension given above? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two conditionals with `and` -- but list comprehensions also support multiple `if`s (which get evaluated with `and`)

Here's two options for what you want:

```
# combining conditions with `and`
output = [
    i.a.get('href') for i in link_data
    if i is not None and i.a.get('href').startswith('https')
]

# combining conditions with multiple `if`s
output = [
    i.a.get('href') for i in link_data
    if i is not None
    if i.a.get('href').startswith('https')
]
```

(note these were indented for clarity, the whitespace between the `[` and `]` is not important)

Comment: You can replace `if i is not None` by `if i`. You are using double negation there

Comment: @Bazingaa they are not equivalent -- for instance `[]` is falsey but not identity to `None`

Comment: I see. In this case yes